# Does anyone have some JMX code for creating a new websphere datasource?

Tags: websphere, datasource, jmx

I'm trying to update the password on a websphere J2C datasource connector using JMX.  Does anyone have any source or tips ?

cheers,

Trevor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code to get the list of datasources configures using JMX:

```
public synchronized List<String> getDBPools() {

    return (List) WSSubject.doAs(this.adminSubject,
            new java.security.PrivilegedAction() {
                public Object run() {
                    // Subject is associated with the current thread context
                    return java.security.AccessController
                            .doPrivileged(new java.security.PrivilegedAction() {
                                public Object run() {
                                    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

                                    try {
                                        Session session = new Session();

                                        // Get the ConfigService
                                        // implementation.
                                        ConfigService configService = ConfigServiceFactory
                                                .getConfigService();
                                        ObjectName dsType = ConfigServiceHelper
                                                .createObjectName(null,
                                                        "DataSource", null);
                                        ObjectName[] datasources = configService
                                                .queryConfigObjects(
                                                        session, null,
                                                        dsType, null);

                                        for (int i = 0; i < datasources.length; i++) {
                                            ObjectName dsObject = datasources[i];
                                            log
                                                    .debug("OBJ NAME = "
                                                            + dsObject
                                                                    .getKeyProperty(SystemAttributes._WEBSPHERE_CONFIG_DATA_DISPLAY_NAME));
                                            log
                                                    .debug("OBJ ID = "
                                                            + dsObject
                                                                    .getKeyProperty(SystemAttributes._WEBSPHERE_CONFIG_DATA_ID));
                                            log
                                                    .debug("OBJ TYPE = "
                                                            + dsObject
                                                                    .getKeyProperty(SystemAttributes._WEBSPHERE_CONFIG_DATA_TYPE));

                                            String dsName = dsObject
                                                    .getKeyProperty(SystemAttributes._WEBSPHERE_CONFIG_DATA_DISPLAY_NAME);

                                            if (!dsName
                                                    .equals("DefaultEJBTimerDataSource")) {
                                                result.add(dsName);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    } catch (ConfigServiceException ex) {
                                        log
                                                .error(
                                                        "Error in JMX Query string",
                                                        ex);
                                    } catch (ConnectorException ex) {
                                        log
                                                .error(
                                                        "Error connecting to the admin service",
                                                        ex);
                                    }
                                    return result;
                                }

                            });
                }
            });
}
```